# CakePHP: 500 Error from any route other than root

Tags: apache, cakephp, routes

I have been trying to learn CakePHP however I have run across an issue where when I try to access any route other than the root I get a 500 error. I have the following set up in my test app.

1) I have the document root for `http://cake.localhost.com/` set to `/app/webroot/`

2) In `/app/Config/routes.php` file I have the following routes set:

```
Router::connect('/', array('controller' => 'posts', 'action' => 'index', 'index'));
Router::connect('/posts/*', array('controller' => 'posts', 'action' => 'view'));
Router::connect('/users/*', array('controller' => 'users', 'action' => 'view'));
```

3) I used the `cake bake` to create the system and it is using a scaffold.

4) When I go to `http://cake.localhost.com/posts/view/1` it gives `HTTP Status Code 500`

If you need any more information please let me know I will be happy to oblige! Thanks for any info in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a legitimate question relevant to core functionality for the entire framework.

1.) Correct.

2.) Configuring routes in the manner you've indicated would result in redirecting all requests to the view action for the specified controller. This is probably not what you had in mind.

Cake's default routing will attempt to route according to naming convention. See [CakePHP broken index method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6526080/cakephp-broken-index-method/6533250#6533250) for routing examples and explanations of their behavior.

3.) Scaffolding is probably not what you had in mind. Scaffolding basically just flags the scaffolded controller to use the Core controller generation default, and skips actually writing the generated code. You might as well generate the defaults; it will give you an idea of basic CRUD, Cake-style.

I cloned your app, applied these steps and everything worked as expected. :) HTH